# How to reroute a View Directory and its content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes, http-redirect

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project. In the project I generated a controller with a name *controller1* which automatically gives me my view files (show, index, and others). This also gives me my url (http://www,website.com/controller1/).

But now I want to change the URL path to another one (http://www.website.com/controls). Is there a way I can do this without having to write route command for each file in the controller1 view folder.

Oh! And I will appreciate options better than the "Moved Permanently" redirect route command code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `routes.rb`

```
resource :controls, controller: 'controller1' # add this line
resource :controller1 # possibly this is in your routes.rb already
```

Reference: [Specifying a Controller to Use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)

Comment: Thanks for this... It works as the question required. But now, I am unable to access the files through the previous URL. (Routing Error: No route matches)

Is it possible to make the previous URL works too?

Comment: @hardeshorlar It works here. Make sure you have `resource :controller1` in your `routes.rb` and you may run `rake routes` to diagnostic the current route mapping to find out more information about problem.

Comment: Hi, Arie... I've tried that but when I put `resources :controller1` and `resources :controls, controller: 'controller1'`, I am only able to access the files though the /controller1/ and /controls/ become unavailable.   When I removed the `resources :controller1`, the /controls/ become unavailable.